# Issue with h1 positioning

Tags: css, html

the h1 in the showcase area is getting on top of each other when i am trying to squeeze the window which is not supposed to behave in that way.But when it is not,, everything is fine. As i am new in this sector, i am not understanding what i've done wrong. Could anyone please show me where it needs to be fixed?
html:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* GLOBAL */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  background-color: #35424a;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #e8491d 3px solid;
}

header a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight,
header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Showcase*/

#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url('../images/showcase.jpg') no-repeat 0 -400px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#showcase h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ACME Web Design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <h1><span class="highlight">Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolor, explicabo voluptas quibusdam dolore omnis maiores quidem necessitatibus nulla, iure ullam asperiores illum. Aliquid fuga magnam labore error vitae laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Subscribe To Our Newsletter</h1>
      <form action="">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="" placeholder="Enter Email">
        <button type="submit" class="button_1">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="images/logo_html.png" alt="">
        <h1>HTML 5 Markup</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto quis consequuntur architecto quos ullam non dolore magni officiis. Veniam maxime labore corrupti voluptatibus! Sequi consequuntur quam laboriosam voluptatibus, at dolorum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="images/logo_css.png" alt="">
        <h1>CSS 3 Styling</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto quis consequuntur architecto quos ullam non dolore magni officiis. Veniam maxime labore corrupti voluptatibus! Sequi consequuntur quam laboriosam voluptatibus, at dolorum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="images/logo_brush.png" alt="">
        <h1>Graphic Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto quis consequuntur architecto quos ullam non dolore magni officiis. Veniam maxime labore corrupti voluptatibus! Sequi consequuntur quam laboriosam voluptatibus, at dolorum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>ACME Web Design, Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Rishad, what would you like for it to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

1. If you want to allow the title to stack for smaller screens you will need to make a small change to your css. I noticed that you have the following line in your css:

line-height: 1.6em;

Try changing this to

```
line-height:1.6;
```

Unitless line heights are typically recommended for use because this will allow the child elements to compute their line heights based on the font size specified.
[Try reading the information here for more in-depth explanation](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/)

2. If you would like for the text to remain on one line when resizing the screen you can use media queries to change the font-size:

Based on your code I noticed that the font begins to stack at 1204px so try adding this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1204px) {
#showcase h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

}

And then from here you can continue on to test the size of the screen and then add more breakpoints based on where the font begins to stack.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add the style `line-height: 55px;` to the `#showcase h1` element, so the height of the text is the same as the size of it.

This is going to be the final result:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* GLOBAL */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  background-color: #35424a;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #e8491d 3px solid;
}

header a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight,
header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Showcase*/

#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url('../images/showcase.jpg') no-repeat 0 -400px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#showcase h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 55px;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ACME Web Design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <h1><span class="highlight">Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolor, explicabo voluptas quibusdam dolore omnis maiores quidem necessitatibus nulla, iure ullam asperiores illum. Aliquid fuga magnam labore error vitae laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Subscribe To Our Newsletter</h1>
      <form action="">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="" placeholder="Enter Email">
        <button type="submit" class="button_1">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="images/logo_html.png" alt="">
        <h1>HTML 5 Markup</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto quis consequuntur architecto quos ullam non dolore magni officiis. Veniam maxime labore corrupti voluptatibus! Sequi consequuntur quam laboriosam voluptatibus, at dolorum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="images/logo_css.png" alt="">
        <h1>CSS 3 Styling</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto quis consequuntur architecto quos ullam non dolore magni officiis. Veniam maxime labore corrupti voluptatibus! Sequi consequuntur quam laboriosam voluptatibus, at dolorum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="images/logo_brush.png" alt="">
        <h1>Graphic Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto quis consequuntur architecto quos ullam non dolore magni officiis. Veniam maxime labore corrupti voluptatibus! Sequi consequuntur quam laboriosam voluptatibus, at dolorum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>ACME Web Design, Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps.